# Why when restarting iOS Simulator my plist becomes binary and lose its data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am successfully able to write a dictionary of information to a plist. I can verify this while running the app by doing:

```
less /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/xxxxxxxx/appname.app/myplist.plist
```

And I see all the data written in xml format as I would expect. (file is about 1KB)

I close down my simulator and reopen it and now I'm told this file is binary and its < 100bytes

I am relatively new to iOS / Objective-c but not sure if there is something I am fundamentally missing about plists and how data is persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you use writeToFile:atomically: method to write the data of an NSDictionary to a file, right?
Like this below:

```
static NSString *filename = @"DictFile.plist";
- (NSDictionary *)openDict
{
    NSString *filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    return dict;
}

- (void)saveDict:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSString *filePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

    if (![dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
    {
        [[NSException exceptionWithName:@"IOException"
                             reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"filename.plist cannot be saved to %@", filePath]
                           userInfo:nil] raise];
    }

    NSLog(@"File on path: %@", filePath);
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Method for checking:

```
- (NSDictionary *)createDict
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [self openDict];

    if (dict)
    {
        id key = [[dict allKeys] firstObject];
        if (key)
        {
            NSLog(@"Found dictionary: %@ - %@", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Key", @"Value", nil];

        [self saveDict:dict];
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: thanks I was using writeToFile but I think the problem was for my path to store the file I was using: 
    NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myplist" ofType:@"plist"]; which was storing the .plist in the .app folder vs the Documents folder. When I use your path it stores it in /Documents and then everything works.